# Why won't the location of the light affect the direction of the shadows?

Tags: rendering, light

So I'm new to blender, and I've been working on a project with a tutorial. (some of you might know this)

I was going through quite smoothly until I noticed that no matter where I place my light, the rendered version appears the same. (directly above the objects) I tried different types of lighting, different brightnesses, (light is currently at around 4.000 brightness) nothing works. But if I delete the light, it becomes dark and grainy. (I checked on the side bar, there are no other light sources or objects..)

Even if I put the light source *under* my objects, the rendered version appears the same.

Am I doing something wrong? Why can't I change the direction of the light?

[image: Light on right]

[image: Light source deleted]

---

Uh.. Since I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links, I'll just post extra info here (also replying to @bertmoog)

I tried changing the light types, but they all do nothing (except for Sun, of course, and Hemi, which is interpreted as Sun for some reason) The brightness is set on 4.200, color set to white, shadows enabled, etc. But it still won't do anything. As you can see, nothing appears in the preview.

[image: (The five light settings)]

**EDIT:** I found that by rotating the sun to point where I want it to, it works almost like normal point lighting (sorta). This pretty much solves my problem, but still, why won't the other lighting modes work?

[image: lighting changes depending on what angle the "sun" light is set]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lighting source is probably set to "Sun".  The sun lamp is meant to emulate a distant light source and therefore, placement is not critical.  In fact, you could place it anywhere and it would have the same effect.  The only things that produce an observable change are the rotation, the intensity/color, and the size.

There are other types of lamps (point, spot) that would work for this scene and you could always try a mesh emission source.  All of these are detailed on this forum.

[image]

***EDIT:*** In response to your answer and comment: it *is* the answer to why your lighting doesn't change no matter where you place the lamp.  The answer is because you have it set to Sun.  I said that rotation is one of the only things you can change about the sun.  Position does nothing.

The reason you're not seeing the lamps is because you aren't choosing the right intensity.  The lamp themselves work perfectly:

[image]

Comment: okay, this didn't exactly solve the problem, but it provided an alternate way to do this bit, so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @BeardWix - see the edit to my answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks to you, I found out why the Sun lamp wasn't working the way I wanted it to. (And also how to make it work the way I wanted it to) But as I already said, none of the other lamps work, no matter at what intensity or angle. (even 100000 strength won't show anything.) BUT since the actual question was answered, I'll probably delete this post and post a new one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BeardWix - There's no reason to delete, it may be beneficial for someone in the future.  You're most welcome, more than happy to help.  I'd like to look at your .blend file if you don't mind... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3559/

Comment: ha ha, I was about to delete it but it recommended me not to.. :d I'll share the file as soon as I can (If I can even figure out how to).

Comment: Here's the link; I didn't put a password on it, since it's based off a tutorial and it's not that good anyways. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3567" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3567/)

Comment: @BeardWix - I took the World environment light down to zero (so you can see the lamp better), changed the sun to "Point", set the strength to 2000, and moved the lamp closer to the donut.  I also added a spot lamp pointing at the cup.  This is not the lighting setup you want for a final render, but it shows that the lights are working  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3569/

Comment: You showcased it! ha ha. Yes, I found out that my lights were in fact working, but for some reason wouldn't light up anything if the brightness was set to less than 10,000. (sun lights up everything at 4.0 brightness!) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BeardWix - No problem at all.  See this article from the manual, look especially at the last two paragraphs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/lamps.html